# Type Error Property of Type Then is Undefined

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

```
Var Map, CachedGeoJson;

var promise = that.map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/31e3j'); 

promise.then(function(data) {
    cachedGeoJson = data; 

    map.data.addGeoJson(
        'https://api.myjson.com/bins/31e3j',
        { idPropertyName: "id"}
    );
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your function, fix the syntax like this:

```
Var Map, CachedGeoJson;

var promise = that.map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/31e3j');

promise.then(function(data) {
    cachedGeoJson = data; 

    map.data.addGeoJson(
        'https://api.myjson.com/bins/31e3j',
        { idPropertyName: "id"}
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a different function to create the promise object since google `loadGeoJson` does not return a promise object.

```
function loadGeoJson(url, options) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
        that.map.data.loadGeoJson(url, options, function (features) {
            resolve(features);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
    return promise;
}

var promise = loadGeoJson('studs.json');

promise.then(function (features) {
    map.data.addGeoJson(
        'https://api.myjson.com/bins/31e3j',
        { idPropertyName: "id"}
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check what properties exist in promise.

```
for (var property in promise) {
    if (promise.hasOwnProperty(property)){
        alert(property);
    }
}
```